# value struct not initialized in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, c++-cx, windows-8.1-universal

For whatever reason, the initialized value of a `value struct` defined in Windows Runtime Component is ignored in the app (C#).

**CX/C++**:

```
namespace RuntimeComponent1
{
    public value struct Foo {
        bool flag1 = true;
        bool flag2 = false;
    };
}
```

**C#**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var settings = new RuntimeComponent1.Foo();
        Debug.WriteLine(settings.flag1); // Output: False
        Debug.WriteLine(settings.flag2); // Output: False
    }
}
```

Notice that `flag1` should be `True` but instead it is `False`. Why? !

---

Edit:
As suggested by @HansPassant, create a ticket for this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2702659
If you also think this is a problem. Please help up voting it.

Comment: Not all languages support constructors for value types (e.g. JS). Therefore, WinRT does not support constructors for value types. (More accurately, constructors for value types are not projected.)

Comment: @RaymondChen kind of make sense. I guess I am more upset about that fact that there is no warnings/errors on this than the fact that it is not supported.

Comment: Feel better about it by reporting this at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: I agree that there should be a warning/error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an email update from Microsoft VC++ team after posting the issue on Microsoft connect https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2702659

> Thank you for reporting this issue.  The next release of the Visual C++ Compiler Toolset will issue an error when a member of a value class has a default member initializer.